# Row Based Filter Not Working With Table Created From Phoenix

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

```
create table empPh2(id integer primary key, fname varchar, lname varchar)COLUMN_ENCODED_BYTES=0 
upsert into empPh2 values (1, 'A', 'B'); 
upsert into empPh2 values (2, 'B', 'B'); 
upsert into empPh2 values (3, 'C', 'B'); 
upsert into empPh2 values (4, 'John', 'B');
```

Then when to `HBase` to do the range query using following command :

```
hbase(main):004:0> scan 'EMPPH2', {STARTROW => '1', ENDROW => '3'} 
ROW                                                COLUMN+CELL                                                                                                                                         
0 row(s) in 0.0030 seconds
```

I saw row in `HBASE` has extra symbols. Not sure how to have `1:1` mapping between `HBASE` table to `Phoenix` table.

```
ROW                                              COLUMN+CELL                                                                                                                                 
 \x80\x00\x00\x01                                column=0:FNAME, timestamp=1532651140732, value=A                                                                                         
 \x80\x00\x00\x01                                column=0:LNAME, timestamp=1532651140732, value=B                                                                                             
 \x80\x00\x00\x01                                column=0:_0, timestamp=1532651140732, value=x                                                                                               
 \x80\x00\x00\x02                                column=0:FNAME, timestamp=1532651151877, value=B                                                                                         
 \x80\x00\x00\x02                                column=0:LNAME, timestamp=1532651151877, value=B                                                                                             
 \x80\x00\x00\x02                                column=0:_0, timestamp=1532651151877, value=x                                                                                               
 \x80\x00\x00\x03                                column=0:FNAME, timestamp=1532651164899, value=C                                                                                         
 \x80\x00\x00\x03                                column=0:LNAME, timestamp=1532651164899, value=B
```

`ROW` filter works fine when table created using `HBASE` but doesn't work when table created with `Phoenix`.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see when doing a full scan on you table (`scan 'EMPPH2'`), rowkeys are not simple strings (like '1' or '3'), but rather byte arrays representing your keys defined in Phoenix (of type `integer`, on 4 bytes). Internal representation of integer `1` for example is `0x80000001` (`10000000 00000000 00000000 00000001` in binary).

So if you want to query your data between row 1 and 3, you must do :

```
scan 'EMPPH2', {STARTROW => "\x80\x00\x00\x01", ENDROW => "\x80\x00\x00\x03"}
```